# Jquery dropdown with json content

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, undefined

So i have two dropdowns, first one is where my products are being showed from json.
Second one are showing models, depended on the first dropdown chooise.
example: first dropdown is showing apple, then second would show iphone models etc.

I have a problem getting the right content in the second dropdown.
Can some one tell me, why the second dropdown is getting filled with "undefined" ?

```
$.each(jsonData.Mobiler, function (key, value) {

    $jsonProducent = key;

    $("#dropdown").append("<option id=" + $jsonProducent + ">" + $jsonProducent + "</option>");

});

// MODElLER

$('#dropdown').change(function () {

    $selected = $(this).find(":selected")[0];

    if ($selected) {
        visModel($selected);
    }
});

function visModel($selected) {
    // testing if $selected.id is right
    alert($selected.id);

    $jsonModel = jsonData.Mobiler + $selected.id;

    // testing if $jsonModel is right
    alert($jsonModel);

    for (var i in $jsonModel) {

        console.log($jsonModel[i].Model);
        $("#dropdown2").append("<option>" + $jsonModel[i].Model + "</option>");
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
$jsonModel = jsonData.Mobiler + $selected.id;
```

I don't understand, why you summarize two objects. You should get array of models by key instead

```
$jsonModel = jsonData.Mobiler[$selected.id];
```

Also you should remove all previous options from `#dropdown2` after each change in `#dropdown` with

```
$("#dropdown2 > option").remove();
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dC2eY/)